# confirm button of Sweet Alert Dialog is displayed too thin

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I use [Sweet Alert Dialog](https://github.com/F0RIS/sweet-alert-dialog) in a project like this:

```
SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(this.getActivity(), SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                .setTitleText(title)
                .setContentText(body);
sweetAlertDialog.show();
```

But the confirm button is too thin:

[image]

I tried to set minimum height for button after showing dialog and re-show that:

```
sweetAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm_button).setMinimumHeight(150);
sweetAlertDialog.show();
```

But it did not solve the problem. Is there a way to correct that?

Comment: I just go through library source code, Library defined static height for confirm button. You have to change that style. check this file https://github.com/F0RIS/sweet-alert-dialog/blob/master/library/src/main/res/values/styles.xml  styled name "dialog_blue_button"

Comment: Apply style as @sanjeev guide you in your sweet Alert Dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it wouldn't work because in the library they have used `style`:

```
<style name="dialog_blue_button" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">31dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/blue_button_background</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">21dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">21dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text_color</item>
</style>
```

So you can set value of height in `styles.xml` and add it to your project. This should work.